# Choices of Message Queue?

Tags: message-queue

We've been using SysV Message Queue for our distributed data processing system for over 15 years. For some reason, we want to replace it with newer Message Queue mechanism. Is there any suggestions?

Requirements:

1. Fast response, minimizing message queue system overhead
2. Multiple client language library support, mainly c, c# and java
3. Can do some HA configuration to prevent SPOF
4. Have logging ability to check who sends message and who receives message

I've found Apache ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ, but it seems RabbitMQ lacks of stable C client library support?

Answer (score 1):

While I have not used it personally, the toolkit from [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is quite impressive.

It seems to meet all of your criteria, although #4 you would have to implement yourself, but that seems straightforward.

My question back would be why you are moving away from SysV Message Queue?  The "for some reason" is a disconcerting statement.

That said, there are many excellent messaging products out there, having a useful set of selection criteria is key.

I would suggest extending your requirements list a bit, then doing website bench-marking against that list.  Take the top two or three only, and do some real-world project spikes (or a bake-off if you prefer the term) to give you some actual feedback on which to base your final decision.

Good Luck